# Open DOS window and spew debug messages from DLL

Tags: c, dll, stdout, labview

I am currently calling a DLL from labview, but I need to be able to debug it realtime (because of it's accessing time sensitive hardware). I would like to just printf() my error assert messages but I am unsure about how to open a DOS window from within the DLL to dump error information to. Has anyone done this before? I know I could do this with a file, and I may have to. printf is just such a handy quick and dirty way to do this though :) .

Comment: I forgot to mention this is windows, although I'm not aware of other operating systems using the .dll (maybe OS2?) for dynamic libraries. Also the DLL is compile with Visual Studio 2008.

Answer (score 5):

1) Make a call to the windows api [AllocConsole](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681944(VS.85).aspx).

2) You will probably need to call [GetStdHandle](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683231(VS.85).aspx) to get stdout/stderr.

3) Printf to your hearts content!

Answer (score 4):

Instead of using printf() you can use Windows's [OutputDebugString()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) function, and check the debug output in [DebugView](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647).

Comment: +1 (earlier), and you'll also get to see what other apps have been sloppy, leaving calls to `OutputDebugString` in their release versions...

Comment: This is also usefull for Qt applications using qDebug