# When debugging on Windows where does stderr go?

Tags: c++, c, windows, stderr

When trying to debug a program on Windows I can't seem to find where the output I push to stderr is going. How do I get a hold of my stderr output? Is there a debugger-level setting (MSVC 9) I can change to redirect stderr to some part of the UI?

Update: I have not looked into `TRACE` or `OutputDebugString`, but the code base is cross-platform, so platform-specific APIs, while not totally off the table, are secondary to a standards-compliant solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you have a GUI process stderror should show up in the output window in visual studio.  You can open a new console window if you want to have the output go there.look at the output. See my answer to [this question.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343304/open-dos-window-and-spew-debug-messages-from-dll) for details.

Answer (score 3):

Another approach, using files:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa236457(VS.60).aspx

Comment: Basically all you have to do is: guiapp.exe 2> stderr.log