# Is there a way to catch the stderr and stdout in Visual Studio?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, command-line, ide, stdout

Is there a way to catch the stdout and stderr in Visual Studio? For example, when I use

```
cout <<"Hello world!"<< endl;
```

A black window appears and disappears. It's so fast that I can't see it. There is a output section in the IDE but it only allow me to choose display output from build and something else but without the choice of stdout.

A cheating solution maybe calling

```
system("pause");
```

but it doesn't sound right. I searched in the option but I can't find an item.

Anyone has any idea? Thanks. I just start to use VS and I'm on Linux before.

Comment: Have a look at the answers here:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1343320/when-debugging-on-windows-where-does-stderr-go

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Rather than using the "Start Debugging" command, if you want to check the output, use "Start Without Debugging". That's generally how I handle it. The command prompt window will remain up until you close it. If there's a crash or something, you can always reattach Visual Studio to the process, or just run it with "Start Debugging".

Answer (score 9):

Go to Project Properties -> Linker -> System -> Change subsystem to Console.

Comment: I changed that but the black window keeps popping up. Where am I suppose to see the output in VS?

Comment: Output will be in the console which pops up. It won't disappear if you go to Debug -> Start without Debugging.

Comment: Not working! Got linking error after this change.  `unresolved external symbol main`. Vs 2019, MFC application Signle Document

Comment: I have set it to Console but the Output window (with "Show output from Debug" selected) does not contain any messages. VS2019

Comment: Rename the entry point to "main" (not "WinMain") in  if you get a linker error after this.

Answer (score 3):

Without actually trying to redirect stdin/err streams, there are some alternatives you can try:

- Open a command prompt window and cd to the directory your executable
  will be created in then run it from there.
- Perhaps try using something like std::cin.get(); or std::cin.ignore(std::cin.rdbuf()->in_avail() + 1); instead of system("pause").
- Display output in the visual studio debugger via [OutputDebugString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363362%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Neither way sounds decent but thanks anyway. It's not your fault. Don't you guys feel inconvenient about this issue? Just curious.

Comment: Change the subsytem to console as I indicated in my answer.

Comment: I knew there was one I was missing, Icemans comment has it correct.

Answer (score -2):

Changing subsystem to console doesn't seem to work with an MFC dialog application.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33869750)