# Can't see Windows command.exe when running my Qt application

Tags: visual-studio-2010, qt

I am currently using VS2010 (with Qt addin). I have run the Hello World Qt example and it works. I get a window where "Hello world" is written. But I can't see the command.exe window. When I use:

```
std::cout << "Windows command test!" << std::endl;
```

Nothing happens, why is it so?

Answer (score 1):

Because you are using wrong project template.

The **Hello world** example that you have successfully built was using `Qt Application` project.

If you'd like to use the command prompt, open a `Qt Console Application` instead.

(picture is from google)

[image]

Comment: Ok, but if I want both: A Qt application and access to my console (for debugging for example). Should I choose a Qt Console Application?

Comment: It's a very good question. [Windows seems to not support both mode at the same time](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3360548/console-output-in-a-qt-gui-app) so I don't have a good answer for you at this moment, but you can take a look at [this thread](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/38171-Both-a-command-line-and-GUI-application-at-the-same-time) (**check the reply of #7**).

Answer (score 0):

Unless Qt is eating your `stdout`, it should still be appearing, but it might be appearing and going away so fast that you do not see it. Take a look at [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10238331/is-there-a-way-to-catch-the-stderr-and-stdout-in-visual-studio) for how to catch it.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to run your program from a cmd.exe windows. This way you can catch all console prints and it never close.